# Are there any (early game) advantages on using wands over other weapons for my Wizard?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are class-specific weapons better than other weapon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63828/are-class-specific-weapons-better-than-other-weapon)

I have a level 10 wizard and I am still using the wand I started with. I noticed my damage seems to fall off in comparison to the other characters I was in game with, who had picked up new weapons as the act progressed (none of which were wizards). That made sense to me as they were melee classes using melee weapons.

I have been reading and apparently I can wield any weapon and my magic damage increases (ok a rusty axe does more magic damage than a crooked wand, weird?!).

After looking quickly at low level weapons, wands seem to offer a pretty low damage output and offer no magic bonus of any kind. Is there any point in using one when I can just use a sword that has a higher damage value?

Comment: I do believe the other question completely covers this one, and already has good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very beginning of the game, no, you probably want to use the item with the highest damage output regardless of what it is.  Later you'll find that wands may offer other bonuses that you'll find desirable, but right out of the gate with mostly vanilla items that isn't a concern.