# Is there an advantage if I use knuckles with monk instead of daggers?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are class-specific weapons better than other weapon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63828/are-class-specific-weapons-better-than-other-weapon)

I am starting with monk and asked a friend what weapon I should use. He told me that my priority should be on knuckles and fist weapons. I started out that way but daggers seem to be much better because of their attack speed. Is it because knuckles work better with a shield or am I missing something? Why prioritise knuckles? Do monks get bonus damage for them or something?

[image]

vs

[image]

Comment: yeah i read that one before posting but i wanted to know the specific differences between daggers and knuckles.

Comment: After reading that question, why would you think there are specific differences between daggers and knuckles?

Comment: Because my friend said something about knuckles giving more spirit then daggers. I got confused and thought this might help me understand it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular fist weapon is poor quality, so don't let the low attack speed throw you off.

Later in the game, magic daggers typically have a base attack speed of **1.50** attacks per second. Fist weapons are a close second at **1.40** attacks per second.

If you *want* to focus on attack speed, by all means try to get these weapon types. But don't limit your options just for that reason. You may find a 1h Spear than is a lot slower but the other stats are so good that its worth using. It's all about your playstyle and what feels good to you.

Also note that later in the game you can find weapons with the + X% Attack Speed affix. I've seen plenty of swords and spears with 1.5 and higher attack speed because of this, and I'm only level 45 so it will surely go higher.

Answer (score 4):

You should go after the highest damage weapons you can get.

In this case the daggers.

Basically your weapon damage is used (buffed by +dmg rings, +dex items, skills etc.) to create you final dmg value.

I think if you enable advanced stats (done in the Diablo 3 settings, like Elective mode), you should be able to see which weapon adds the most dmg.