# What are the best weapon types for each class in Diablo III?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are class-specific weapons better than other weapon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63828/are-class-specific-weapons-better-than-other-weapon)

Does it matter what kind of weapon you equip, for example a crossbow vs. a sword ? Are any specific classes stronger when using a certain weapon, for example a Wizard using a wand ?

I am most interested in hearing about the Witch Doctor class.

Answer (score 0):

The weapon class doesn't matter at all.

Your indicator is the Damage number in your character screen after you equip the weapon.  Due to stat modifiers, like dex, str, or int (depending on class), attack speed increase, and crit; just because one weapon has a higher DPS displayed, doesn't mean it will give you a greater dps for your character.

So go ahead, use a bow :P